# How to hide text under ads

Tags: html

I don't know if it's the right term but i want to hide text with ads. So when user is using adblock plugin, the text will appear.

I'm new to html so idk if this is correct. Is it possible to do it with just html?
I tried doing this but the text is just at the bottom of the ad.

```
<div>
<center>
<!--
Ad code 728x90
-->
<h3>Please disable your Ad-Blocker</h3>
</center>
</div>
```

I've seen so many websites with this feature, but i'm not sure how to do it.
please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is by placing the text underneath the banner ad. If the user has adblock enabled the ad is invisible and thus your text is visible. If he has adblock turned off the ad will cover the text.

You can achieve this by placing a div which is surrounding the ad content and the text like this:

```
<div class="ad-container">
//Your Ad code here
<h3>Please disable your Adblock</h3>
</div>
```

To get this to work you need to make the elements inside the container position:absolute;

I made a fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/q671xyq5/

If you delete the image (that's basically what adblock does) the text appears.

Comment: that's what i want, but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack could be to give the element where the Ad code will be placed an `id` then use javascript/jquery to check the contents of the Ad. If it can't find it, display your text

Comment: but how can i achive this?
btw the ad provider is adsense if that could help.

Comment: could you post a snippet of what the general Ad content after it's loaded would look like?